# Getting this error : Object Expected in Javascript on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, onkeydown

I have found a code on stackoverflow allows automated conversion on Internet Explorer 8 of keyboard keys from azerty keyboard to Arabic characters, but I'm getting an error which I haven't understood
here is the complete error :
Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Thu, 9 Jan 2014 16:15:04 UTC


Message: Object expected
Line: 78
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/home$/Bureau/nice%20conversion.html
```

The error is pointing to this line of javascript code :

```
$("#foo").keypress(function(evt) {
```

here is the complete snippet of code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function transformTypedChar(charStr) {
    return charStr == "a" ? "b" : charStr;
}

function getInputSelection(el) {
    var start = 0, end = 0, normalizedValue, range,
        textInputRange, len, endRange;

    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        start = el.selectionStart;
        end = el.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        range = document.selection.createRange();

        if (range && range.parentElement() == el) {
            len = el.value.length;
            normalizedValue = el.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");

            // Create a working TextRange that lives only in the input
            textInputRange = el.createTextRange();
            textInputRange.moveToBookmark(range.getBookmark());

            // Check if the start and end of the selection are at the very end
            // of the input, since moveStart/moveEnd doesn't return what we want
            // in those cases
            endRange = el.createTextRange();
            endRange.collapse(false);

            if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                start = end = len;
            } else {
                start = -textInputRange.moveStart("character", -len);
                start += normalizedValue.slice(0, start).split("\n").length - 1;

                if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                    end = len;
                } else {
                    end = -textInputRange.moveEnd("character", -len);
                    end += normalizedValue.slice(0, end).split("\n").length - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
}

function offsetToRangeCharacterMove(el, offset) {
    return offset - (el.value.slice(0, offset).split("\r\n").length - 1);
}

function setInputSelection(el, startOffset, endOffset) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = startOffset;
        el.selectionEnd = endOffset;
    } else {
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        var startCharMove = offsetToRangeCharacterMove(el, startOffset);
        range.collapse(true);
        if (startOffset == endOffset) {
            range.move("character", startCharMove);
        } else {
            range.moveEnd("character", offsetToRangeCharacterMove(el, endOffset));
            range.moveStart("character", startCharMove);
        }
        range.select();
    }
}

$("#foo").keypress(function(evt) {
    if (evt.which) {
        var charStr = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
        var transformedChar = transformTypedChar(charStr);
        if (transformedChar != charStr) {
            var sel = getInputSelection(this), val = this.value;
            this.value = val.slice(0, sel.start) + transformedChar + val.slice(sel.end);

            // Move the caret
            setInputSelection(this, sel.start + 1, sel.start + 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
<textarea id="foo" cols="80" rows="8">Type in here and any 'a' will be you type will show up as a 'b'</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Could somebody please explain what is the problem here ?

Comment: I don't see jQuery included here, did you remember to include jQuery.  Also, your code won't work because you are trying to bind the event before the `foo` element exists.  You need to wrap your code in `$(function(){ // your code });` so that it runs at the correct time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you have missed to include jquery core library. You have used jquery function but not mentioned anywhere about it's reference. Please download or include http://jquery.com/download/ jquery library.

Comment: Thanks @Ravimallya :), How can I include the jquery library ?

Comment: Just save http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js this file in your directory or use cdn path as described here https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?csw=1#jquery

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code just below your `<head>` tag.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Although javascript is natively supported in all browsers, you must link any libraries you are making use of.